# Nginx & Https Redirection

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have an ssl certificate for www.domain.com.
Obviously if someone goes to https: //domain.com, they will get an error from the browser 
about a certificate mismatch.  Is it possible to setup the webserver to redirect requests 
from https:// domain.com to https:// www.domain.com?

In nginx, I've been trying variations of this, but to no avail:

```
server {
  listen   443;
  server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
  if ($host !~ www.domain.com) {
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 permanent;
  }
}
```

Edit: Just to clarify if anyone hits the site at via plain http, it's not a problem, I already can redirect them to https:// www.domain.com, which is correct.  It's only if they manually type https:// domain.com, that I don't know how to do the redirection.

Comment: It is possible, but anyway request to https://domain.com/ would show cert warning before redirect. You need to fix your certificate, not redirects.

Comment: For the correct method check out this post: http://serverfault.com/a/337893/26204

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, a redirection response can only take place *after* the SSL session has been established.

This is clearly a certificate issue; you need a certificate that contains `www.domain.com` with `domain.com` as the SAN (Subject Alternative Name). Most CA's give a single SAN for free, e.g., digicert.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
 listen 443;
 servername www.domain.com domain.com;

 if ($host ~ ^(?!www)) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.$host/$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

second thought it might be better to use two server blocks:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name  domain.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443; 
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    hosting configuration here
}
```

EDIT: What about adding domain.com as a SubjectAltName in your SSL Cert so you don't have to rewrite. Perhaps ask your CA if this is possible?

- [ssl certificate for www.example.com and example.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/132468/ssl-certificate-for-www-domain-com-and-domain-com)
- [How to install a single SSL certificate for www and non-www](https://serverfault.com/questions/226289/how-to-install-a-single-ssl-certificate-for-www-and-non-www)

Worst case, shell the $$ for a certificate to domain.com :D

Comment: Yea, I had tried something similar.  I do have two separate blocks for regular http, and that works perfectly.  Every request that doesn't match www.domain.com is sent to www.domain.com and all the configuration is there.  The same thing doesn't work for https though.  My guess is that it simply can't work with https, it's probably a limitation of the protocol because it wants to create the secure connection before processing the redirect.

Comment: I think you're right, its prob something particular to SSL and likely by design

Comment: relevant thread with nginx creator: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,84559

Comment: TLDR; thread implies you may need the certificate for domain.com as well

Comment: Sadness, I just read it.  It makes sense why that is the case, but unfortunate none the less.

Comment: Hmm, your links made me think that perhaps I can get around the problem with a self signed certificate for each the other domains, because at least that would allow it to make the secure connection and then do the redirect.  If they come via plain http it's never a problem, only if they manually type in https://domain.com, which I doubt many people would even do.  Not sure exactly what the browser will do, but I'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to push users to a https service:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mail.polemon.org;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://mail.polemon.org$1 permanent;
}
```

and this is a catch-all rule:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name polemon.org *.polemon.org;

  if ($host != polemon.org) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://polemon.org$1 permanent;
  }
}
```

The catch-all has to be defined last, otherwise other subdomains won't work.

And here's another example, how to deal with people that have no `Host:` header line:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name _;
  server_name_in_redirect off;

  root /var/www/jail/;
  index index.html;
}
```

As a side note, you can create certificates for wildcarded DNS names. Those are called "wild certificates", and even if they're valid, Firefox users still get warnings.